# How to fit a smooth curve to my data in R?

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting

I'm trying to draw a smooth curve in `R`. I have the following simple toy data:

```
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> y
 [1]  2  4  6  8  7 12 14 16 18 20
```

Now when I plot it with a standard command it looks bumpy and edgy, of course:

```
> plot(x,y, type='l', lwd=2, col='red')
```

How can I make the curve smooth so that the 3 edges are rounded using estimated values? I know there are many methods to fit a smooth curve but I'm not sure which one would be most appropriate for this type of curve and how you would write it in `R`.

Comment: It entirely depends on what your data is and why you're smoothing it! Are the data counts? Densities? Measurements? What sort of measurement error might there be? What story are you trying to tell your readers with your graph? All of these issues affect whether and how you should smooth your data.

Comment: These are measured data. At x values 1, 2, 3, ..., 10 some system made 2, 4, 6, ..., 20 errors. These coordinates should probably not be changed by the fitting algorithm. But I want to simulate the errors (y) at the missing x values, for example in the data, f(4)=8 and f(5)=7, so presumably f(4.5) is something between 7 and 8, using some polynomial or other smoothing.

Comment: In that case, with a single data point for each value of x, I wouldn't smooth at all. I'd just have big dots for my measured data points, with thin lines connecting them. Anything else suggests to the viewer that you know more about your data than you do.

Comment: You may be right for this example. It's good to know how to do it though, and I might want to use it on some other data later, e.g. it makes sense if you have thousands of very spiky data points that kind of go up and down, but there is a general trend, for example going upward like here: plot(seq(1,100)+runif(100, 0,10), type='l').

Comment: Here is a good way, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278666/134555

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I like `loess()` a lot for smoothing:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(2,4,6,8,7,12,14,16,18,20)
lo <- loess(y~x)
plot(x,y)
lines(predict(lo), col='red', lwd=2)
```

Venables and Ripley's MASS book has an entire section on smoothing that also covers splines and polynomials -- but `loess()` is just about everybody's favourite.

Comment: How do you apply it to this data? I'm not sure how because it expects a formula. Thanks!

Comment: As I showed you in the example when if `x` and `y` are visible variables. If they are columns of a data.frame named `foo`, the you add a `data=foo` option to the `loess(y ~ x. data=foo)` call -- just like in almost all other modeling functions in R.

Comment: i also like `supsmu()` as an out-of-the-box smoother

Comment: how would that work if x is a date parameter? If I try it with a data table that maps a date to a number (using ```lo <- loess(count~day, data=logins_per_day) ```) I get this:
```Error: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
```

Comment: @Wichert Akkerman It seems that date format is hated by most R functions. I typically do something like new$date = as.numeric(new$date, as.Date("2015-01-01"), units="days") (as described on https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/162719.html)

Comment: What if line mostly vertical (i.e. many different y's for single x)?

Answer (score 68):

Maybe smooth.spline is an option, You can set a smoothing parameter (typically between 0 and 1) here

```
smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(x, y, spar=0.35)
plot(x,y)
lines(smoothingSpline)
```

you can also use predict on smooth.spline objects. The function comes with base R, see 
?smooth.spline for details.

Answer (score 28):

In order to get it REALLY smoooth...

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(2,4,6,8,7,8,14,16,18,20)
lo <- loess(y~x)
plot(x,y)
xl <- seq(min(x),max(x), (max(x) - min(x))/1000)
lines(xl, predict(lo,xl), col='red', lwd=2)
```

This style interpolates lots of extra points and gets you a curve that is very smooth.  It also appears to be the the approach that ggplot takes. If the standard level of smoothness is fine you can just use.

```
scatter.smooth(x, y)
```

Answer (score 26):

the *qplot()* function in the ggplot2 package is very simple to use and provides an elegant solution that includes confidence bands.  For instance,

```
qplot(x,y, geom='smooth', span =0.5)
```

produces
[image]

Comment: Not to dodge the question, but I find the reporting of R^2 (or pseudo R^2) values for a smoothed fit to be dubious.  A smoother will necessarily fit closer to the data as the bandwidth decreases.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph

Comment: Hmm, I could not finally run your code in R 3.3.1. I installed `ggplot2` successfully bu cannot run `qplot` because it cannot find the function in Debian 8.5.

Answer (score 15):

LOESS is a very good approach, as Dirk said.

Another option is using Bezier splines, which may in some cases work better than LOESS if you don't have many data points.

Here you'll find an example: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cubic_bezier_curves#R

```
# x, y: the x and y coordinates of the hull points
# n: the number of points in the curve.
bezierCurve <- function(x, y, n=10)
    {
    outx <- NULL
    outy <- NULL

    i <- 1
    for (t in seq(0, 1, length.out=n))
        {
        b <- bez(x, y, t)
        outx[i] <- b$x
        outy[i] <- b$y

        i <- i+1
        }

    return (list(x=outx, y=outy))
    }

bez <- function(x, y, t)
    {
    outx <- 0
    outy <- 0
    n <- length(x)-1
    for (i in 0:n)
        {
        outx <- outx + choose(n, i)*((1-t)^(n-i))*t^i*x[i+1]
        outy <- outy + choose(n, i)*((1-t)^(n-i))*t^i*y[i+1]
        }

    return (list(x=outx, y=outy))
    }

# Example usage
x <- c(4,6,4,5,6,7)
y <- 1:6
plot(x, y, "o", pch=20)
points(bezierCurve(x,y,20), type="l", col="red")
```

Answer (score 13):

The other answers are all good approaches.  However, there are a few other options in R that haven't been mentioned, including `lowess` and `approx`, which may give better fits or faster performance.

The advantages are more easily demonstrated with an alternate dataset:

```
sigmoid <- function(x)
{
  y<-1/(1+exp(-.15*(x-100)))
  return(y)
}

dat<-data.frame(x=rnorm(5000)*30+100)
dat$y<-as.numeric(as.logical(round(sigmoid(dat$x)+rnorm(5000)*.3,0)))
```

Here is the data overlaid with the sigmoid curve that generated it:

[image: Data]

This sort of data is common when looking at a binary behavior among a population.  For example, this might be a plot of whether or not a customer purchased something (a binary 1/0 on the y-axis) versus the amount of time they spent on the site (x-axis).

A large number of points are used to better demonstrate the performance differences of these functions.

`Smooth`, `spline`, and `smooth.spline` all produce gibberish on a dataset like this with any set of parameters I have tried, perhaps due to their tendency to map to every point, which does not work for noisy data.

The `loess`, `lowess`, and `approx` functions all produce usable results, although just barely for `approx`.  This is the code for each using lightly optimized parameters:

```
loessFit <- loess(y~x, dat, span = 0.6)
loessFit <- data.frame(x=loessFit$x,y=loessFit$fitted)
loessFit <- loessFit[order(loessFit$x),]

approxFit <- approx(dat,n = 15)

lowessFit <-data.frame(lowess(dat,f = .6,iter=1))
```

And the results:

```
plot(dat,col='gray')
curve(sigmoid,0,200,add=TRUE,col='blue',)
lines(lowessFit,col='red')
lines(loessFit,col='green')
lines(approxFit,col='purple')
legend(150,.6,
       legend=c("Sigmoid","Loess","Lowess",'Approx'),
       lty=c(1,1),
       lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("blue","green","red","purple"))
```

[image: Fits]

As you can see, `lowess` produces a near perfect fit to the original generating curve.  `Loess` is close, but experiences a strange deviation at both tails.

Although your dataset will be very different, I have found that other datasets perform similarly, with both `loess` and `lowess` capable of producing good results.  The differences become more significant when you look at benchmarks:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(loess(y~x, dat, span = 0.6),approx(dat,n = 20),lowess(dat,f = .6,iter=1),times=20)
Unit: milliseconds
                           expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval cld
  loess(y ~ x, dat, span = 0.6) 153.034810 154.450750 156.794257 156.004357 159.23183 163.117746    20   c
            approx(dat, n = 20)   1.297685   1.346773   1.689133   1.441823   1.86018   4.281735    20 a  
 lowess(dat, f = 0.6, iter = 1)   9.637583  10.085613  11.270911  11.350722  12.33046  12.495343    20  b
```

`Loess` is extremely slow, taking 100x as long as `approx`.  `Lowess` produces better results than `approx`, while still running fairly quickly (15x faster than loess).

`Loess` also becomes increasingly bogged down as the number of points increases, becoming unusable around 50,000.

EDIT:  Additional research shows that `loess` gives better fits for certain datasets.  If you are dealing with a small dataset or performance is not a consideration, try both functions and compare the results.

Answer (score 9):

In ggplot2 you can do smooths in a number of ways, for example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.3, se = FALSE)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: is it possible to use this geom_smooth for further processes?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see this method shown, so if someone else is looking to do this I found that ggplot documentation suggested a technique for using the `gam` method that produced similar results to `loess` when working with small data sets.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- 1:10
y <- c(2,4,6,8,7,8,14,16,18,20)

df <- data.frame(x,y)
r <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))+geom_point()
r
```

[First with the loess method and auto formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArzPW.png)
[Second with the gam method with suggested formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx1dy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the [ggscatter](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggscatter.html) function from the `ggpubr` package. By specifying `add="loess"`, you will get a smoothed line through your data. In the link above you can find more possibilities with this function. Here is a reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset:

```r
library(ggpubr)
ggscatter(data = mtcars,
          x = "wt",
          y = "mpg",
          add = "loess",
          conf.int = TRUE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>