# I want a "line of best fit" on a scatter plot of predictor variable "RM" to outcome (known in data) "Price" before regression?

Tags: r, visualization

In "R", I want to overlay a "line of best fit" on a scatter plot, (using raw data), of the predictor variable "RM" on the x-axis and outcome variable "Price" on the y-axis. (The data contains the variable "Price" that will eventually be predicted on new data using ln() and pred()). I'm reviewing this plot **before** doing regression on the data for the purpose of determining if RM is significant (influences Price ... if it has a linear distribution tendency). If the plot shows no relationship I will drop it from the data set before doing linear regression ln() and prediction on it. I'm doing this on each potential predictor variable.

Do I somehow calculate the y-int and slope first? If so, how?

```r
BostonHousingW.df <- read.csv("BostonHousing.csv")
plot(BostonHousingW.df$Price ~ BostonHousingW.df$RM, 
     xlab="Avg # of Rooms", 
     ylab="Median Home Price",
     main="Boston Housing Data\n Median Home Price and Avg # of Rooms")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480460/12957340

Comment: Or perhaps just `cor(RM, Price)`

Comment: I've searched and found only one variant (in many locations) of a `BostonHousing.csv` dataset, and it contains neither `$Price` nor `$RM`. Lacking usable data ... I'm out.

Comment: Why are you using a plot to determine what is significant? You should be running your regression and looking at your coefficients from there to determine what's significant. Please also consider how to [make a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), such as including a data set that can be used to evaluate your code.

Comment: I prefer stats myself but using visualizations was part of the assignment.