# How to smooth the line in R ggplot without using ggalt library

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

`df <- data.frame( posting_year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), value = c(492, 523, 507, 66, 58, 641, 226, 990, 555, 481) )`

This is the line chart I get using this code:

`ggplot(df, aes(x=posting_year , y=value)) +  geom_line()`

[image]

But I want a line chart with a curve line. Something like this

[image]

Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480388/how-to-fit-a-smooth-curve-to-my-data-in-r

Comment: You could use `geom_smooth` but the approximation is not exactly the one you represent here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use geom_smooth here, but default you get not what you try to achieve. Default is the blue one, playing around with span gives more or less the desired result in red.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = posting_year, y = value)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, se = F, span = 0.75, color = "blue") + # default span
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, se = F, span = 0.20, color = "red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach that is close to what you want. You can define `stat_smooth()`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=posting_year , y=value)) +  
  geom_line(color = 'red', size=1)+
  geom_smooth(method = "loess",
              se = FALSE,
              formula = 'y ~ x',
              span = 0.2, 
              size=1)+
              theme_bw()
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame( posting_year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), value = c(492, 523, 507, 66, 58, 641, 226, 990, 555, 481) )
```

[image]