# My smooth spline plot does not look like a curve

Tags: r, plot, smoothing, spline

I believe that this plot should look like a smooth curve, but my plot is showing straight connected lines. Can someone point out my error?

```
Y <- c(0,2,-1,4)
t = c(1:4)
plot(t,Y)
c = smooth.spline(t,Y,lambda=1)
lines(t,c$y)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am guessing you don't have enough datapoints. Use the spar argument for smoothing. See related, possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480388/680068

Comment: @Johnny did my response below resolve your problem? If so, please up vote my response! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using the `loess()` command.

Here you go:

```
Y <- c(0,2,-1,4)
t = c(1:4)
plot(t,Y)
lo <- loess(Y~t)
lines(predict(lo),col="blue", lwd=1.5)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `qplot()` function, found in `library(ggplot2)`

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(t,Y, geom='smooth', span =0.5)
```

[image]